# 作業途中のgit

Tags: git

git管理している開発で、作業の途中(コミットするには中途半端)のものを一時的に保存する方法はありませんか?

今はやむを得ず「途中」というコメントでコミットしています。

シチュエーションとしては、しばらく作業から離れる時や、別のPCで作業を再開したい時などがあります。

Comment: stashを調べてみて下さい。

Comment: stashがまさしくそのために使えます

Comment: 可搬性を考えると、質問文中にあるような、作業途中のものをcommitする運用に特段違和感は無いのですが、何か問題があると考えられているのでしょうか。
(他の方が回答されている`git-stash`や`git-diff`では「別のPCで作業を再開したい」ことも考えると力不足ではないかと考えます。)

Comment: 「途中」というコミットメッセージのような作業途中のコミットを運用上許可し最終的にコミットを綺麗にしたいという目的であれば、--amendやrebase -i（歴史の書き換えも問題ないというスタンスなのであれば）も手段としてはありえるのでやはりどのようなことがしたいかはっきりしないと回答となりうる方法がありすぎる気がします。

Answer (score 3):

- **patch**で作業を一時的に保存する.
  作業の追加

  ```
  git add .
  ```

  保存

  ```
  git diff >> patchfile
  ```

  後は

  ```
  patch -p1 < patchfile
  ```
- **stash**で作業を一時的に保存する
  作業の追加

  ```
  git add .
  ```

  保存

  ```
  git stash
  ```

  メッセージをつける

  ```
  git stash save 'メッセージ'
  ```

  保存されている状態のリストを見ることができる。

  ```
  git stash list
  ```

  前の作業をもどして

  ```
  git stash apply
  ```

Comment: git add . しないと新規ファイルが含まれないのは、diff/patchの方法でも同じではないでしょうか？

Comment: そうですね、 忘れていました。 ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

`wip` などのコミットメッセージで、ひとまずコミットして、他の端末で利用するならば、(作業用ブランチに)プッシュをします。

特に、ローカルのみで完結する場合でも、最近は stash ではなく commit を利用しています。なぜかというと、 stash はついうっかり drop してしまうともうその内容は基本的にリカバリーできないですが、 commit ならば reflog が残っていて、そこから復旧できるからです。

Comment: 同意です。私も最初の頃はstashを使っていましたが、今は適当なコメントでコミットして、作業に戻るときに`git reset HEAD^`してます。

Answer (score 2):

Qiitaの記事の[Gitのこれやめて！リスト](http://qiita.com/doilux/items/b5a9abd95ac91e848a5f)の[「その３：とりあえずコミットしてPushするのやめて」](http://qiita.com/doilux/items/b5a9abd95ac91e848a5f#%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%EF%BC%93%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8A%E3%81%82%E3%81%88%E3%81%9A%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6push%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%82%84%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6)の対策として書かれているように、それ用のブランチを作ってコミット＆プッシュすれば良いのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

以前同じようなことを調べた時に[git-now](https://github.com/iwata/git-now)というツールを見つけたのでそれを使っています。
`git now`で一時コミットを作成し、`git now rebase`で一時コミットをまとめて`rebase -i`できます。

やっていることは一時コミットを作ることと同じなので、pushするのであれば専用のブランチを作ってからにした方が良いと思います。